# How can I customize create in controller in Sails

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have created a Comment Model that has One-to-One associoation.

```
// api/models/Comment.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    user: {
      model: 'user',
      unique: true,
    },

    comment: {
      type: 'string'
    },
  }
};
```

And a HTML form to create it.

```
<form method="POST" action="/comment">
    <!-- send logged user -->
    <input type="text" name="workingRegion" placeholder="City">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

How can I add the userId before create the comment (assuming that the user is logged using Passport.js (userId in req.session.user)?

I was thinking about customize `create()` in CommentController, but I don't know how.
    create: function(req, res) {
        if (!req.session && !req.session.user) //using Passport
            //error

```
    //save() ?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// api/controllers/CommentController.js

create: function(req, res) { 
    var params = req.params.all();
    params.user = req.session.user.id;

    Comment.create(params)
    .exec(function(err, comment) {
        //do stuff here
    });
}
```

Then create a policy that checks to ensure the user has an active session.

```
// api/policies/sessionAuth.js

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  // this assumes you created an "authenticated" flag for the session
  // when the user logged in
  if (req.session.authenticated) {
    return next();
  }

  return res.forbidden('You are not permitted to perform this action.');
};
```

Comment: Can I do this? override method `create()` then call him inside my method? like super.create()? Isn`t it strange?

Comment: Sorry it may not have been clear at first, I added a comment to hopefully improve the clarity.  The model method create() isn't being over-ridden.  The snippet I included should be placed in CommentController.js and then called by POSTing to /comment.  If you have  blueprints enabled, the "create" blueprint will be over-ridden (which is what you want, since you're doing more than saving the values that were supplied by the user / frontend.